# Bootstrap 2 Fixed Menu Issue On Small Devices

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have built a template based on Bootstrap 2.3.2 framework. On small view ports I have made the menu fixed.

The issue is when the menu is viewed in iPhone5 landscape mode OR Crappy Android portrait OR Crappy Android landscape, only few menu are seen.

The User can't scroll down to other menus nor scroll down to see the page content unless they close the menu.

Here is the test URL: http://www.godtry.ivanbayross.com/

If you view the test URL in http://www.responsinator.com/ you will see the problem when viewing iPhone 5 landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
#headerWrapPhone {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background: #0E2371;
}
```

Basically all you need to do is remove the `position:fixed` on that class. It keeps it covering up the rest of the screen all the time if it's open.

Comment: but if i remove the position:fixed then the menu will not be fixed. it will scroll above as the page scrolls... what i want is that the menu remains fixed and the page scrolls below it....

Comment: That's what happens already. The issue is the height. Content is scrolling underneath the fixed nav, but the fixed nav height covers up the content until it's clicked off. Remove the min-height and margin-top from #topMenu and users will see a little of the content below, letting them know to click off the menu to see it. This is really the way Bootstrap is supposed to work, so there isn't really a fault with it. You'll just have to make the drop-down in mobile have less height.